# In FireFox webm don't support but in Chrome the same webm support

Tags: php, xml, firefox

Here is my code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Arpit
 * @copyright 2012
 */

$crxml=file_get_contents('latest.xml');
$rss=new SimpleXMLElement($crxml);
$playlistitem=1;
foreach($rss->channel->item as $post)
{

    if($playlistitem<=8)
    {    
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li class="xdesc">'.$post->description.'</li>';

    $dc=$post->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    echo '<li class="xthumb">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';
    echo '<li class="xpreview">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';

    echo '<li class="xsources_mp4">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';

   $dc->content->attributes()->url=preg_replace('/.mp4/','.webm',$dc->content->attributes()->url);

    echo '<li class="xsources_webm">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    $playlistitem++;
    }

}


?>
```

When I change the extension to webm in both xsources_mp4 and xsource_webm then it again work in chrome but in Firefox it show **undefined** when i Firebug it and the video fail yo play.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers use different formats for playing content, some event support more than one. Check [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Table) which browser supports what.

Comment: No but when I add manually the  code ir <li>path.webm</li> that work in Firefox but when  I call it from xml file it didn't work.